# jquery: render only <A> tag and keep others as it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i have a text containing normal text, html code and link then I want to render only `a` tag inside a given `div` other tag should be displayed as it is inside a given `div`

e.g.

```
// expected output: <h1>HTML CODE</h1> link
$("#d1").append("<h1>HTML CODE</h1> <a href=''>link</a>");

// expected output: <h1>HTML CODE</h1> <strong>xyz</strong>
$("#d2").append("<h1>HTML CODE</h1> <strong>xyz</strong>");

// expected output: <h1>HTML CODE</h1> link
$("#d3").text("<h1>HTML CODE</h1> <a href=''>link</a>");
```

OR, take another example lets say i have a text

`<small>hello </small> hw r u here is <a href=''>link</a><h6>thank you</h6>`

i want the output like

`<small>hello </small> hw r u here is link <h6>thank you</h6>`

How can i do that. **[HERE IS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7EP7D/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending a text node instead of a string - use [document.createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode)

```
$("#d2").append(document.createTextNode("<h1>HTML CODE</h1> <strong>xyz</strong>"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L6rc9/)

Comment: it is same a `text` right? but my question is i just want to avoid html tag other the `a`

Answer (score 1):

Try this as chain your jQuery with `.text()` and `.append()` this way:

```
// expected output: <h1>HTML CODE</h1> link
$("#d3").text("<h1>HTML CODE</h1>").append("<a href=''>link</a>");
```

because `.text()` push the html string as a textnode that is why your link is not appended as a link. you have to append it.

Comment: how about a given text `<small>hjhjh</small> hello hw r u <a href=''>link</a><h6>hhhhhhhhhh</h6>`. How will you render this?